# Repeating script every 5 seconds not overlapping existing runs with crontab and watch

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I know crontab can only schedule tasks down to the minute and to schedule something more often than 60 seconds another method has to be chosen.  My understanding is `watch` will wait for the process to finish before starting another.  Can crontab and watch be combined or is this truly a horrific idea?

`* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/script.lockfile /usr/bin/watch -n 5 /usr/bin/php /home/user/script.php`

Conceptually, we use flock to create a lock file to prevent cron from restarting the watch command which would otherwise start every 60 seconds.  Watch then starts and keeps the script running every 5 seconds.

Comment: Can you tell more about what the script does?

Comment: It makes an API request, though I don't see how it's relevant to the question.  I'm aware of the ability to write a wrapper to handle the script repetition, or using `flock()` directly in the script.  I'm more curious on the potential pitfalls of using crontab in the way I suggested. @EduardoTrápani

Comment: I thought that maybe a service would make for a better pattern for that task (sleeping between tries, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's truly horrific, but if you look at the current implementation you'll notice that the end result is a `watch` (the first one) running forever.

While that happens you are asking cron to run `flock -n`, which will *always* fail, since `watch` is going to be running forever, keeping the original lock alive.

If it is something to be running at all times (it looks like that from the cron entry), you could consider running the `watch` (or a looping script with a sleep) at boot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, I would agree with your interpretation of the command but I think you're overlooking the intent.  I'm trying to create a way to ensure the watch command is running, under normal circumstances it will be.  However, if the watch command were killed and not started from crontab then it wouldn't be running forever.

Comment: @Brian `cron` is meant to start a command at regular intervals/times. You are misusing it, that is the answer to your question. But if you had already decided that's the way to go, well, then go that way. It'll work, but it's a waste of resources.

Comment: If you start watch at boot and then someone kills the watch process what keeps it running? @EduardoTrápani